# Is there a way to quickly get rid of a lot of excess data with regex searches?

Tags: python

I'm trying to pull a few pieces of data for data entry into a server. I've gotten the data from a web API, and they include a lot of information that to me, is garbage. I need to get rid of a ton of it, but I'm having issues with where to start. The data I need is up until "abilities", and then starts again at "name":"Contherious". [And here's that link](http://txt.do/158ps). Most of the data processing I've been doing has been trying to use regex searches to try to process this, and the only search I can think of is that between the names that I need versus the names that I don't need have a space and lead to ID directly after them. I'm just unclear as to how to grab each and every one of these names and any help would be appreciated.

I've tried

```
DMG_DONE_FILE = "rawDmgDoneData.txt"

out = []

with open(DMG_DONE_FILE, 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        regex_id = search('^+"name":"\s"+(\w+)+"id":',line)
        if regex_id:
            out.append(regex_id.group(1))

        line = f.readline()
```

and I get errors because I generally don't know what I'm doing with regex searches

Comment: Not really a regex problem.  Better to use json tools.  A great cmdline tool is jq https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

Comment: How would I use the json tools if things are named the same? E.g. I have things with the variable "name" before them that are irrelevant to my data set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import sys
import json

# use urllib to fetch from api 
# example here for testing is reading from local file
f=open('file.json','r')
data=f.read()
f.close()
entries = json.loads(data)
```

Now you have a data structure that you can easily address

e.g.  entries['entries'][0]['name']

alternatively using jq  https://stedolan.github.io/jq/

```
cat file.json |jq '.entries[]| {name:.name,id:.id,type:.type,itemLevel:.itemLevel,icon:.icon,total:.total,activeTime:.activeTime,activeTimeReduced:.activeTimeReduced}'
```

Comment: Wow, that is way better with jq, also, is there an easy way to pull this into a file to be able to parse over this later for entry into a database?

Comment: I found out a way to pipe it to stdout, thank you very much, got everything I needed :D